# Clustered Columnstore with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-6, sql-server-2014, columnstore

I have a table with a Clustered Columnstore index. This table cannot have a primary key because of the index. It actually has an ID column, but I cannot put an index on it.
Entity Framework demands a Key, otherwise it marks it as read only. How can I tell EF what the key is?

Comment: Did you try the Key attribute?

Comment: The Key attribute worked. I will put a more detailed answer in when I get time.

Comment: @Founder, can you please share your solution? i'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to add a key to the edmx. Open the EDMX, right click the column and select entity key